# Extracting parts of JSON from json.loads list in python

Tags: python, arrays, json, dictionary, nlp

I have ~100k JSON files, each containing JSON which I am looping through to create a bag of words model - very simple. Each JSON file looks like this:

```
[{"tokens":[{"word":"Voices","lemma":"voice","pos":"NNS","ner":"O"},{"word":"from","lemma":"from","pos":"IN","ner":"O"},{"word":"Russia","lemma":"Russia","pos":"NNP","ner":"LOCATION"}],"dependencies":[{"head":0,"dep":2,"label":"prep_from"}]},{"tokens":[{"word":"Wednesday","lemma":"Wednesday","pos":"NNP","ner":"DATE"},{"word":",","lemma":",","pos":",","ner":"DATE"},{"word":"11","lemma":"11","pos":"CD","ner":"DATE"},
....
```

What I need is to extract only the values of the `"word"`  keys for each file, and store this array in a new file called so each file has an array like:

`["Voices", "from", "Wednesday","Russia", "," ,"11"...]`

And also I have a similiar array for all the files put together, stored in `../../data/train_jsons/all_words.json`

However `json.loads` creates a list for each item not a dict. How can I achieve what I want just from looping through the list for each file, and store these individual arrays of words in new files that maintain the name of the filepath of the json e.g. new files called `../../data/train_jsons/words_for_.........json`?

Trying to transform to a dict and using the key "word" doesn't seem to work per:

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk('../../data/train_jsons'):
    for file in files:
        filepath = subdir + os.sep + file
        if filepath.endswith(".json"):
            with open(filepath) as data_file:
                data = json.load(data_file)
                dict = dict(itertools.izip_longest(*[iter(data)] * 2, fillvalue=""))
```

Speed is a key factor in my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with 
    d=[{'tokens': [{'lemma': 'voice', 'ner': 'O', 'word': 'Voices', 'pos': 'NNS'}, {'lemma': 'from', 'ner': 'O', 'word': 'from', 'pos': 'IN'}, {'lemma': 'Russia', 'ner': 'LOCATION', 'word': 'Russia', 'pos': 'NNP'}], 'dependencies': [{'dep': 2, 'head': 0, 'label': 'prep_from'}]}]

this worked for me

```
[u['word'] for u in x['tokens'] for x in d]
```

Comment: Thank you ! This worked, I just converted to `for x in data:
                    for u in x['tokens']:
                        print u['word']`

Comment: The solution is very slow unfortunately though, as I have around 100,000 json files like the above. Is there a solution that might be faster?

Comment: Prints are slow, you can prealocate by defining a big list that you fill in your loop. Then you can multithread and consider PyPy.